# PHP array doesnt return value

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a PHP file will should return me an array from a mysql. The problem is that the array is not passing.

If I query for 2 or more columns the array is null.

```
<?php 
//conection: 
$mysqli = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","imoveis") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($mysqli)); 


//consultation: 

$query = "SELECT * FROM saomiguel" or die("Error in the consult.." . mysqli_error($mysqli)); 


//execute the query. 

$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);

//display information: 

$response = array();

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // looping through all results
    // products node    
    $response["saomiguel"] = array();       

      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        // temp user array
        $product = array();     
        $product["id"] = $row["id"];
        $product["second"] = $row["second"];

        // push single product into final response array
        array_push($response["saomiguel"], $product);
    }
    // success
    $response["success"] = 1;
    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);

} else {
    // no products found
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "No products found";

    // echo no users JSON
    echo json_encode($response);  

        // closing db connection
        mysqli_close($mysqli);

}
?>
```

if i set the echo response inside  the while loop it only returns one row.

ATTENTION:

JUst found the error! Inside one of my columns I had "Imóvel" the ´ was giving me a error! i was using it as varchar, size 75, charset latin1.

Does the charset raise me the problem?

Edit:

Solve the problem by adding

$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");

Comment: Your `or die` statement on the query declaration should be moved down to the `mysqli_query` call. Maybe the query fails?

Comment: no it runs. I have discovered now that if i delete my second row (i have 19) i all runs fine.  The strange... its only that line if i delete others i doesnt show  the array

Answer (score 0):

You should remove this line

//display information:

$response = array();

Can you please try this. And let me know if it work.

```
<?php 
//conection: 
$mysqli = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","imoveis") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($mysqli)); 


//consultation: 

$query = "SELECT * FROM saomiguel" or die("Error in the consult.." . mysqli_error($mysqli)); 


//execute the query. 

$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);


if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // looping through all results
    // products node    
    $response["saomiguel"] = array();       

      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        // temp user array
        $product = array();     
        $product["id"] = $row["id"];
        $product["second"] = $row["second"];

        // push single product into final response array
        array_push($response["saomiguel"], $product);
    }
    // success
    $response["success"] = 1;
    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);

} else {
    // no products found
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "No products found";

    // echo no users JSON
    echo json_encode($response);  

        // closing db connection
        mysqli_close($mysqli);

}
?>
```